# Which polarizer is better

Tags: nikon, sigma, polarizer

I have been looking at get a polarizer and some nd filters for my sigma 50mm art lense. From my research, it looks like the best are B+W and Hoya. Does anybody have any experience with either brand on full frame or can suggest an alternative?

Also, anybody know of nd filters that will fit on a sigma 12-24? I have see a few "home made" ones on the net, but I'm not crazy about trying to make one.

Shooting a d810 body

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the polarizer, in my opinion there is not much to choose between the 2 you mention, however, there is one that I prefer for my high end 50 mm 1.2 when I am out and about. That is the Tiffen circular polarizer. It is a fairly expensive option, but the build quality matches my lens and keeps in line with the premium feel.

However, my main reason is that it is not as dark as the Hoya which I also have but does the exact same job but more vibrant. This means that I can keep it on the lens all the time except for night.